# Ember CLI in production having issues talking to Sails.js API on Apache Server

Tags: node.js, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ember.js

Problem: Internal Server error when trying to proxy API calls from built ember app to production Node API, with .htaccess on CentOS with Apache.

Using Ember CLI 1.1.15

Enviroments.js file:

```
var ENV = {
modulePrefix: 'va-loans-frontend',
environment: environment,
baseURL: '/',
locationType: 'auto',
host: 'http://localhost:1337/api',
...

if (environment === 'production') {
    ENV.host = "http://example.com:80/api";
}
```

.htaccess located in `home/example/public_html`

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

#redirect all page requests to main index
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(index\.html|robots\.txt|img|font|js|css|scripts|action/.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^api/ http://example.com:8080/ [P, L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ /index.html [NC,L,QSA]
#ProxyPassReverse /api http://example.com:8080/
```

(`RewriteCond` and `ProxyPassReverse` being commented out is me just trying to simplify and rule out specific lines)

I've also tried using a virtual host with `proxypass` rules and rewrite inside with no dice.

If I comment out the first `RewriteRule ^api/*` then apache serves my ember app and even does page redirects correctly but none of my api calls work then as they all get redirected to `index.html`.

My sails.js server is set to listen on port 8080 and is running in production mode with pm2. My built ember-cli project sits in my `/public_html` folder and looks like so:

`assets/, crossdomain.xml, .htaccess, index.html, robots.txt`.

Summery: Have apache serve `index.html` (my built ember-cli app) and redirect any url requests that don't contain `/api/` to `index.html` so that ember can handle the routing. Any requests that *do* contain `/api/` should be proxied to `port 8080` where my sails.js node API lives and be handled there where it will eventually pass JSON back to my ember application.

Comment: I've actually been at this for a week, and that's like my 17th iteration of an `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a way around this. The way around it was to cut Apache out as the middle man.

I dropped the `.htaccess` file completely and used iptables to do the redirect from port 80 to port 8080 where my sails application resided.

I then moved my built ember application to the assets folder inside of sails and added the following route to the bottom of my routing file in `sails/config`.

```
 '/*': {
      controller: 'App',
      action: 'serve', 
      skipAssets: true, 
      skipRegex: /^\/api\/.*$/
  },
```

And my `sails/api/controllers/AppController.js` file looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
    serve: function(req, res){
        res.sendfile( directory_path_to_my_project + '/assets/index.html');
    }
};
```

And of course all my routes are pre-pended with `/api` and this seems to have been working perfectly so far.

I came to this solution after reading: [here](http://www.programwitherik.com/five-tips-when-working-with-routes-on-sails-js/), [here](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/1423), [here](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/1203), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22561257/simple-page-app-routes-to-same-view-or-controller-sailsjs), and [here](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/routes/custom-routes) and well many many other places.